# Text View (Code View) in WordPress Customizer TinyMCE Editor

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer, tinymce

I have implemented TinyMCE Editor in WordPress Customizer by putting this code in functions.php file:

```
// TinyMCE Editor in Customizer
if (class_exists('WP_Customize_Control')) {
  class Text_Editor_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    function __construct($manager, $id, $options) {
      parent::__construct($manager, $id, $options);

      global $num_customizer_teenies_initiated;
      $num_customizer_teenies_initiated = empty($num_customizer_teenies_initiated)
        ? 1
        : $num_customizer_teenies_initiated + 1;
    }
    function render_content() {
      global $num_customizer_teenies_initiated, $num_customizer_teenies_rendered;
      $num_customizer_teenies_rendered = empty($num_customizer_teenies_rendered)
        ? 1
        : $num_customizer_teenies_rendered + 1;

      $value = $this->value();
      ?>
        <label>
          <span class="customize-text_editor"><?php echo esc_html($this->label); ?></span>
          <input id="<?php echo $this->id ?>-link" class="wp-editor-area" type="hidden" <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo esc_textarea($value); ?>">
          <?php
            wp_editor($value, $this->id, [
              'textarea_name' => $this->id,
              'media_buttons' => false,
              'drag_drop_upload' => false,
              'teeny' => true,
              'quicktags' => false,
              'textarea_rows' => 5,
              // MAKE SURE TINYMCE CHANGES ARE LINKED TO CUSTOMIZER
              'tinymce' => [
                'setup' => "function (editor) {
                  var cb = function () {
                    var linkInput = document.getElementById('$this->id-link')
                    linkInput.value = editor.getContent()
                    linkInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
                  }
                  editor.on('Change', cb)
                  editor.on('Undo', cb)
                  editor.on('Redo', cb)
                  editor.on('KeyUp', cb) // Remove this if it seems like an overkill
                }"
              ]
            ]);
          ?>
        </label>
      <?php
      // PRINT THEM ADMIN SCRIPTS AFTER LAST EDITOR
      if ($num_customizer_teenies_rendered == $num_customizer_teenies_initiated)
        do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
    }
  }
}
```

But it only displays editor view, How can I make it display 'text view' (Code View) too.

Comment: Try setting `quicktags` to a `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as @Sally CJ posted comment in my question.

Setting quicktags to true did the job for me.